# Is it better to use varchar for a single sub category that has multiple values?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm quite new at this so I wanted some feedback on how I should structure these categorical databases.

So let's say we have a LED computer fan. The LED fan has colors and I want the users to be able to filter by color. Evidently, there is a quite a number of colors so I have come to 3 conclusions to implement this.

1. Use ENUM. However, I have read a few threads about using it which could be problematic and have almost ruled this one out.
2. Create a column for each color and use boolean values to check off which 
   color the led fan would be. I assume this method would use up more performance, but I'm no expert and stand to be corrected.
3. Use varchar and enter the color values manually and potentially risk wrong input values being entered but saving performance?(Question mark because I have no clue about performance in databases.)

If I could get some opinions, I would appreciate it! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Mainly depends on a) they queries that are going to happen, b) are more than one category for the same item possible c) how often are categories going to be added. If in doubt about database performance, try and see.

Comment: Usually you should put these options in separate table and use one-to-many or many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Create the `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements for each implementation.  This exercise may lead you to make your own decision.